# What is source of Earth's potential energy when an object is raised to a height from Earth?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, planets

If a ball is lifted against gravity, the work we do is stored as potential energy in it. Simultaneously earth too develops the same amount of potential energy due to the height of which the object is raised. What is the source of energy for earth's potential energy?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the Earth nor the ball have potential energy themselves. The energy belongs to the *pair* of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever energy was used to move them away from each other has increased the gravitational potential of each towards each other.